# react-scripts start error (Cannot find module '../scripts/start') - how can i fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting 'Error: Cannot find module '../scripts/start' from projects set up using create-react-app that previously worked fine, now when i run 'npm start' i'm getting this error - the only workaround seems to be rm -rf node_modules followed by npm install, but next day I run into the same problem. Any ideas how to fix this please (see full error message below) - thanks.

```sh
>react-scripts start

module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../scripts/start'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:18:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/DANTHORY/Dropbox/card-slider-challenge_TESTING/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts:28:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! card-slider-challenge@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the card-slider-challenge@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name":"card-slider-challenge",
  "version":"0.1.0",
  "private":true,
  "scripts":{
    "start":"react-scripts start",
    "build":"react-scripts build",
    "test":"jest",
    "eject":"react-scripts eject",
    "start-api":"json-server --port 3001 --watch --static none data/db.json"
  },
  "dependencies":{
    "react":"^16.3.2",
    "react-dom":"^16.3.2",
    "react-slick":"^0.23.2"
  },
  "devDependencies":{
    "jest":"^24.0.0",
    "json-server":"^0.12.2",
    "react-scripts":"^1.1.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: add `.js` to the end of the `../scripts/start`

Comment: How does your `package.json` look like?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix to this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue and I did the following:

1. Delete node_modules folder
2. Run npm install

It fixed my issue, but what it caused, I don't know.

Comment: According to another [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56293430/14499516) question, it appears that `node_modules` would not be override thoroughly when `npm install` is called again. So yeah, although the cause is still unknown, this is probably the best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my computer and I clone my projet from Github

1. Delete `node_modules` folder
2. Run `npm install`

Comment: This is the exact same answer as the one posted 2 years ago. I voting to close it.