# What does "npm install" when "node_modules" exits?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

What's the effect of "npm install" when you have a "package.json" and a "node_modules"-directory as well in your project-directory?

Does it overwrite the existing modules? Does it update them or does it nothing at all?

Comment: npm install just install everything mention in package.json, if installed already then it will not going to update until and unless version change/package name change

Comment: @iamrajshah Ah, okay ... It compares the version of the local-module with the current version in the npm-repository? And when the repository-version is higher then it does an update? Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Yeah!!! repository version / updation of package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Algorithm Section](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#algorithm) in the official [NPM Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

---

> - load the existing node_modules tree from disk
> - clone the tree
> - fetch the package.json and assorted metadata and add it to the clone
> - walk the clone and add any missing dependencies
>
>   - dependencies will be added as close to the top as is possible
>   - without breaking any other modules
> - compare the original tree with the cloned tree and make a list of
> - actions to take to convert one to the other
> - execute all of the actions, deepest first
>
>   - kinds of actions are install, update, remove and move

---

So no, it does not override every existing package again. 
It fetches all packages and compares the meta data between the package trees and the package file.