# How to check and fix dependencies errors?

Tags: reactjs, npm, scripting

i've been facing several problems trying to creat a react application.  Today i wrote the npx create-react-app and a problem occured; i discovered that i should have installed node.js before doing so, so i installed it and then ran again that command. This time it worked but after the npm start, 191 vulnerabilities jumped out and also, looking some videos on youtube, while other peoples had like "61 packages" i had like 1900. Here the errors that occurs if i write npm audit. I don't know how all of that happened, i tried to use audit fix --force and npm i --package-lock-only and also to unistall and reistall node.js plus then 1 time and restarted my pc, but nor of those things works. Do you know how can i solve that? and also how can this affect my projects?

`PS C:\Users\giann> npm audit
npm ERR! code ENOLOCK
npm ERR! audit This command requires an existing lockfile.
npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only
npm ERR! audit Original error: loadVirtual requires existing shrinkwrap file

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\giann\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-11-06T17_57_26_681Z-debug-0.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above error likely states that you do not have a `package-lock.json` file in your directory. Perhaps the below steps could fix your problem:

1. Uninstall and reinstall your `Node.js` from https://nodejs.org/en (it should automatically comes with a brand new `npm` as well).
2. If not, browse this stackoverflow question and do it manually yourself: [How to Reinstall Broken npm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748308/14499516)
3. Delete the existing `node_modules` folder, `package.json` file and `package-lock.json` file from your directory.
4. In the target directory, input `npm start` again.

The reasons of the above steps is that `node_modules` would not be thoroughly overwritten if the `meta-data` exists correctly when `npm install` is executed([What does "npm install" when "node_modules" exits?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56293430/14499516)). And in this case if the 1600+ packages are not what you needed, it is better to delete all of them than trying `npm audit` (and it might likely not fixed your bugs if you don't know how to use the information).